# bitbake SRC_URI file://

Tags: path, environment-variables, uri, yocto, bitbake

If I have a tarball, helloworld.tar.gz in a local directory, say /home/user/tarballs/, how can I make my bitbake recipe fetch from that directory?

my helloworld.bb is

```
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "Proprietary"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING; md5=1b1b8016e15e07a2fec59623ebf12345"

SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.tar.gz"
```

but when I bitbake, I get the below warning message:

```
WARNING: Unable to get checksum for helloworld SRC_URI entry helloworld.tar.gz: file could not be found
```

I read something about FILES and FILESEXTRAPATHS can influence the download path but not sure where/how to set them.

I did a bitbake -c show FILESEXTRAPATHS but get an error message:

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'FILESEXTRAPATHS'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, if you want to fetch from a local directory, use e.g.:

```
SRC_URI = "file:///home/user/tarballs/helloworld.tar.gz"
```

The FILES and FILESEXTRAPATHS variables tells bitbake where to find files which are referenced as:

```
SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.tar.gz"
```

These files are searched for in the locations specified by those two variables. (Or rather, FILESEXTRAPATHS is searched and then some possible subdirectories of the directories specified in FILESEXTRAPATHS, amongst those the expanded values of DISTRO, MACHINE, ARCH, etc).

FILES (and FILESEXTRAPATHS) are used to find files stored together with the meta-data, i.e. under the paths meta-*/recipes-*/name/XXX.

See http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.7/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-FILES and http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.7/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-FILESEXTRAPATHS

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I could put the entire absolute path inside SRC_URI.

Answer (score 7):

Better you can keep your files in present(where the .bb file present) directory and give the below lines in your .bb file.

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.tar.gz"
```

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend : tells to bitbake  the files are present in where the .bb file is present.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can edit .bb file as follows,

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "path_to_home_folder_of_source_folders:"
SRC_URI = "file://Source_floder/*"
```

as an example

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "/home/username/:"
SRC_URI = "file://tarballs/*"
```

Comment: Just wondering what if you have no tarball but a directory tree with sources