# fetching from local directory

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Posted a question on Yocto mailing list but didn't get an answer. Hopefully someone can provide one here.

We are storing some of the source code locally on a machine. Found
this on how to do it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27834916/1636521,
but for some reason it doesn't work for me. I'm pretty sure I'm
missing something but don't know what exactly.

Here is my recipe

```
SUMMARY = ""
DESCRIPTION = ""
# Licensing Meta-data
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

# Modify these as desired
PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "            \
            file://app.tgz \
          "
DEPENDS += "\
    libevent \
    "

do_compile () {
  export SWROOT=${S}/../app
  oe_runmake
}

do_install () {
:
}
```

And here is the error that I'm getting:

```
Loading cache: 100%
|###########################################################################################################|
Time: 0:00:01
Loaded 3265 entries from dependency cache.
WARNING: /home/user/projects/petalinux-build-system/sources/core/../meta-piccard/recipes-piccard/cpe/cpe.bb:
Unable to get checksum for cpe SRC_URI entry app.tgz: file could not
be found
Parsing recipes: 100%
|#########################################################################################################|
Time: 0:00:04
Parsing of 2476 .bb files complete (2470 cached, 6 parsed). 3269
targets, 229 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.32.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "universal"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "zynq-generic"
DISTRO            = "petalinux"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "2017.3"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon
callconvention-hard       cortexa9"
TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
meta
meta-poky         = "HEAD:8506cec55de8950e89a4d3e786860f1086782587"
meta-perl
meta-systemd
meta-gpe
meta-python
meta-efl
meta-ruby
meta-filesystems
meta-gnome
meta-multimedia
meta-networking
meta-webserver
meta-xfce
meta-initramfs
meta-oe           = "HEAD:a9887ac249b81fcac3007244d0c807c71b73acef"
meta-linaro-toolchain = "HEAD:39860f6c7af0858981cc004bbe4f4c421f6be607"
meta-qt5          = "HEAD:eec778bfb9a0b5494d593a2d7bb02c027b641835"
meta-xilinx       = "HEAD:04a45809e0bc42b35c88f8a08305d82fd25e97cf"
meta-xilinx-tools = "HEAD:37eff634934efac72d3e2eabb7c4f8d0c8a36fbb"
meta-petalinux    = "HEAD:d74ceaef26e606c2761edfc3446d0ad3c3cc8b8e"
meta-virtualization = "HEAD:cbfd4376d5e9d229f857151ffdfb57fbc6c0c40d"
meta-openamp      = "HEAD:cfeca8988418e4967f0d6df828d23a1540ae25a0"
meta-swupdate     = "HEAD:6c066d36b1c3c6d46f16c09efe5fb7681bbf3dc5"
meta-piccard     = "master:9f114a33df76a3c3f40eca12b7195ff8ebaad876"
workspace         = "HEAD:51fa75c5477e29285bbbe810f4327b26d80d511d"
```

Here is the `ls` of the recipes directory,

```
$ ls ~/projects/petalinux-build-system/sources/meta-piccard/recipes-piccard/cpe/files

app  app.tgz

The output of

bitbake cpe -e | grep FILESEXTRAPATHS

produces the following line

FILESEXTRAPATHS="/home/userl/projects/petalinux-build-system/sources/core/../meta-piccard/recipes-piccard/cpe/files:__default:"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Logs are truncated. I'm not sure you can point to something outside ${S} folder (`export SWROOT=${S}/../app`). do_install contains `:` character?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the license file checksum, do like below commands

```
md5sum apps.tgz
```

e.g :

> siva@siva-Vostro-3268:~$ md5sum hello.tar.gz
>    `62390830e7933767d5e3bd080d619c70`  hello.tar.gz

Then copy the number and paste into you recipe(.bb)using the variable see below,

```
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "62390830e7933767d5e3bd080d619c70"
```

or

```
SRC_URI += "file://app.tgz;md5=xxxxxx"
```

Comment: Ain't it more: `SRC_URI += "file://app.tgz;md5=xxxxxx"`